# Accessing custom module in Electron package

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp

We have created a custom module which communicates with the Desko Penta Scanner device. We are successfully able to access this module when we run Electron  without package it.  When I package the same Electron and try to access it by opening the exe file I am not able to.  Below is the path of my electron project

```
 locales
resources
  |---- app
    |   
    ------- build
        |   
            Release
        |   
        example.node --> Module which we are tryig to access in preload.js


    node_modules
    bindin.gyp
    example.cxx
    preload.js
    electron.asar

electron.exe
```

We are accessing like this
var example = require('./build/Release/example');